# SSE/AVX + OpenMP: fast sum of arrays

Tags: c, openmp, sse

I am summing two arrays and outputing a third array (not a reduction).  Like this:

```
void add_scalar(float* result, const float* a, const float* b, const int N) {   
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

I want to do this with the maximum throughput.  With SSE and four cores I naively expect a speed up of 16 times (four for SSE and four for the four cores).  I have implemented the code with SSE (and AVX).  Visual studio 2012 has auto-vectorization but I get better results by "unrolling the loop".  I run my code for arrays (with 32 byte alignment) with four sizes: less than 32KB, less than 256KB, less than 8MB, and greater than 8 MB coressponding to the L1, L2, L3 Caches, and Main memory.  For L1 I see about a 4x speedup using my unrolled SSE code (5-6 with AVX).  That's as much as I expect.  The efficiency drops for each cache level after that.  Then I use OpenMP to run on each core.  I put "#pragma omp parallel for" before my main loop over the array.  However, the best speedup I get is 5-6 times with SSE + OpenMP.  Does anyone have a clue why I'm not seeing a speedup of 16x?  Maybe it's due to some "upload" time of the array from system memory to the cache?  I realize I should profile the code but that's another adventure in itself that I have to learn.

```
#define ROUND_DOWN(x, s) ((x) & ~((s)-1))  
void add_vector(float* result, const float* a, const float* b, const int N) {
    __m128 a4;
    __m128 b4;
    __m128 sum;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < ROUND_DOWN(N, 8); i+=8) {
        a4 = _mm_load_ps(a + i);
        b4 = _mm_load_ps(b + i);
        sum = _mm_add_ps(a4, b4);
        _mm_store_ps(result + i, sum);
        a4 = _mm_load_ps(a + i + 4);
        b4 = _mm_load_ps(b + i + 4);
        sum = _mm_add_ps(a4, b4);
        _mm_store_ps(result + i + 4, sum);
    }
    for(; i < N; i++) {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My wrong main loop with a race condition something like this:

```
float *a = (float*)_aligned_malloc(N*sizeof(float), 32);
float *b = (float*)_aligned_malloc(N*sizeof(float), 32);
float *c = (float*)_aligned_malloc(N*sizeof(float), 32);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n=0; n<M; n++) {  //M is an integer of the number of times to run over the array
    add_vector(c, a, b, N);
}
```

My corrected main loop based on Grizzly's suggestions:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    results[i] = (float*)_aligned_malloc(N*sizeof(float), 32);
}
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for(int t=0; t<4; t++) {
    for(int n=0; n<M/4; n++) { //M is an integer of the number of times to run over the array
        add_vector(results[t], a, b, N);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: Like you I haven't profiled the code, so I can not answer with absolute certainty.

Your problem is most likely related to Memory bandwidth or parallelization overhead.

Your loop is very computation-light, since it does 1 add for 3 memory operations, making you naturally limited by memory bandwidth (considering that ALU thoughput is much better then memory bandwidth in modern architectures). Therefore most of your time is spent transfering data.

If the data is small enough to fit the cache you could (theoretically) bind the openmp threads to specific cores and ensure the correct part of the vector is in the L1/L2 cache of the specific core, but that won't really help, unless you can parallelize the initialization (it doesn't really matter when you transfer the data, if you have to do it anyways). So you are taking a hit from fransfering data from one cores cache to another.

If the data doesn't fit the processor caches you are ultimately limited by the bandwidth to main memory. Due to prefetching one core might be able to almost max out the bandwidth for such an easy access pattern, giving you little room to grow.

The second point to remember is, that creation of a `omp parallel` construct and distributing the loop has a certain amount of overhead. For small datasets (The datasets fitting the L1/L2/L3 probably qualify) this overhead can easily be as high as the computation time itself, giving you little to no speedup.

Comment: How do I bind OpenMP threads to specific cores?  This is more for experimentation (establishing upper bounds on what can be done) so the data size is whatever I make it.  I added the code for my main loop.  I loop several times over the array so I think I remove the OpenMP overhead.

Comment: @raxman: Depends on your OpenMP runtime. For GOpenMP it would be the [GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html#GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY) environment variable, no clue about others. However looking at your main loop, I'm supprised you actually get a speedup: You parallelize over your executions of `add_vector`, while executing all `add_vector` operations *on the same data*. This is a) a race condition (unprotected writes from several threads at the same address) and b) permanently makes the cores exchange their cachelines between each other

Comment: @raxman I doubt thread-binding will do much. For the sizes that fit in cache, you will be bottlenecked by the load/store throughput.

Comment: @Grizzly I think you're right.  I did not think I had a race condition but I see what you mean.  I'll check that and get back to you.  

Do you have a better suggestion for timing my code than looping over the array several times and using a timer?

Comment: @raxman: Well, you could use a different result array for each thread, which would solve the race condition and the cache ping pong (of course increasing the working set in the process, so your L3 size would be off). The real question is what you are actually trying to measure. Working the same data over several times is kind of wasteful afterall, so that probably isn't the scenario you would actually get in reality. So how would you see your parallelization in reality?

Comment: @Grizzly: You were correct.  After many false tries I did what you wrote (see the code above).  I made different result array for each thread and decreased the l3 array range.  Now I get 14x SSE (18x AVX) for L1, 9x SSE (7.5X AVX - slower?), 6x SSE/AVX L3, and 2.4x SSE/AVX on main memory.  In each case I compare the speed with the scalar function in that range.  Race conditions are a lot more subtle and hard to debug than I expected.

My goal is to do image processing, e.g. convolutions and re-sampling, with SSE/AVX+OpenMP (without Intel IPP) and compare the results with my OpenCL code.